# BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'userNameInput'

Tags: python, html, database

`Part Of Python:

```
    elif request.form['btn_form'] == "save_owner":
        print("[LOG] button save class clicked")
        print("[LOG]", request.form["userNameInput"])
        print("[LOG]", request.form["firstNameInput"])
        print("[LOG]", request.form["lastNameInput"])
        print("[LOG]", request.form["dateOfBirthInput"])
        print("[LOG]", request.form["emailInput"])

        insert_into_tbl_owner({
            "userNameInput": request.form["userNameInput"],
            "firstNameInput": request.form["firstNameInput"],
            "lastNameInput": request.form["lastNameInput"],
            "dateOfBirthInput": request.form["dateOfBirthInput"],
            "emailInput": request.form["emailInput"]
        })

        sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_owner"
        results = fetch_all_with_column_names(sql)
        results["owner_name"] = "owner"

    elif request.form['btn_form'] == "save_card":
        print("[LOG] button save card clicked")
        data = {
            "mobInput": request.form.get("mobInput"),
            "heartsInput": request.form.get("heartsInput"),
            "damageInput": request.form.get("damageInput"),
            "blockHeightInput": request.form.get("blockHeightInput"),
            "versionAddedInput": request.form.get("versionAddedInput"),
            "rarityInput": request.form.get("rarityInput"),
            "costInput": request.form.get("costInput")
        }
        insert_into_tbl_mobs(data)

        sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_mobs"
        results = fetch_all_with_column_names(sql)
        results["mob_name"] = "mob"
```

Part of Html:
`

```
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Add User</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Add User</p>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="userNameInput" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userNameInput"
                            name="userNameInput" aria-describedby="userNameInput">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="firstNameInput" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstNameInput"
                            name="firstNameInput" aria-describedby="firstNameInput">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="lastNameInput" class="form-label">Last Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastNameInput"
                            name="lastNameInput" aria-describedby="lastNameInput">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="dateOfBirthInput" class="form-label"> Date Of Birth:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateOfBirthInput"
                            name="dateOfBirthInput" aria-describedby="dateOfBirthInput">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="emailInput" class="form-label"> Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailInput"
        `                    name="emailInput" aria-describedby="emailInput">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#05376B;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-             dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_form" value="save_card">Save</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>`
```

I dont know whats wrong with my code and im getting the title error anytime i try to add a new card and the error is telling its an error for the usernameInput even though its part of the new owner area. Im kinda new to python so help would be very much appreciatied.

Thanks